# FontIcon's style override by local properties

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to externalize all my components' style so I can reuse them when needed.

I have a resource named **MainMenuItemFontStyle** with several setters including a FontSize setter to 14.

When I apply this resource to my FontIcon, the Style gets override by some local parameters. The problem is that I never set these local parameters and I can't find them.

The styles are in a separate file (*Styles.xaml*) and looks like :

```
<Style x:Name="FontIconBase" TargetType="FontIcon">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Name="MainMenuItemFontStyle" TargetType="FontIcon" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FontIconBase}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

I called it simply with a **Style** parameter :

```
<FontIcon Grid.Column="0" Glyph="{Binding Icon}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MainMenuItemFontStyle}"/>
```

And this is what I get from the properties explorer :

[image: Properties explorer]

As you can see, my styles are presents but there is some local parameters. And the link to *MainContainerView.xaml* point to the **FontIcon** displayed before.

Am I doing it the wrong way ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you share FontIconBase Style as well

Comment: Done, it's just a setter to the FontFamily property.

Comment: Remove MainMenuItemFontStyle  from MainContainerView.xaml

Comment: Sorry, thought that it was clear from the screen that the styles are in a separate file, named Styles.xaml. I'm editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually noticed this too, recently.

It appears that the `FontIcon` class is setting the value 20 as the `FontSize` dependency property's local value, which will take precedence over the style setter. I checked the docs and it didn't mention any specific reason why it is doing so, so I think it may be a bug. Really the default value for a dependency property should be set via the [dependency property metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/hh702105). [Here's a link to a feedback hub post I made](http://aka.ms/Uhiyio) if you want to upvote it to their attention.

You can fix this by calling `ClearValue(FontSizeProperty)` on the specific `FontIcon` instance, or just subclass it and use the subclass in place of `FontIcon`:

```
public class FontIconFixed : FontIcon
{
    public FontIconFixed()
    {
        ClearValue(FontSizeProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, the subclass do the trick.
Unfortunately, I cannot access your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think the MainContainerView.xaml also has the style MainMenuItemFontStyle in which the fontsize is 20. Hence the style you have written on Styles.xaml is being overridden.

Comment: I've just double checked it, the style is only declared once in the *Styles.xaml* file and used once in the **FontIcon** component.